# Launching firefox....(selenium)

Tags: selenium

i am running a selenium code on visual studio 2008. the code is like this..

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Selenium;

namespace SeleniumTests
{
[TestFixture]
public class MyFirstVCTest
{
    private ISelenium selenium;
    private StringBuilder verificationErrors;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetupTest()
    {
        selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://demo.volunteercampaigns.com/");
        selenium.Start();
        verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TeardownTest()
    {
        try
        {
            selenium.Stop();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Ignore errors if unable to close the browser
        }
        Assert.AreEqual("", verificationErrors.ToString());
    }

    [Test]
    public void TheMyFirstVCTest()
    {

        selenium.Open("/?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1");
        selenium.Click("link=Login");
        selenium.WaitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.Type("id=ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtEmailAddress", "elonadn@ebees.com");
        selenium.Type("id=ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtPassword", "bees123");
        selenium.Click("id=ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnlogin");
        selenium.WaitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.Click("id=ctl00_lblUserName");
        selenium.Click("id=ctl00_lnkSignOut");
        selenium.WaitForPageToLoad("30000");
    }
}
}
```

i started selenium server server using following command(in command prompt)

```
java -jar selenium-server.jar
```

i got the following screen[image]

and i started running my program. but i got a empty firefox window. now the command prompt changed as

[image]

why it is halted at Launching firefox?? please help..

my firefox version is 11.0 and selenium version is 2.20.0

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error is that you have chrome listed in your config. Shouldn't it be *firefox?

Comment: Hm. My only other guess is that Selnium 2 doesn't support Firefox 11. I had limitations with older versions of Selenium where it didn't support the latest versions. I would experiment with other versions..Even IE or Chrome as it supports almost every browser under the sun (just not always latest versions)

Comment: Yes, it looks like other people are having issues with Firefox 11 in Selenium 2 http://groups.google.com/group/selenium-users/browse_thread/thread/4cf721d0c14f2d7e/73ba90cec25e92da?lnk=raot  I would try to downgrade to Firefox 10

Comment: yes. you are correct. i just installed ff4 and its working fine. thank u very much.. :)

Comment: "chrome" in Selenium RC means Firefox.  It's a long-standing usage, popularized by the Mozilla Foundation long before Google decided to call their browser "Chrome".  Selenium RC uses "googlechrome" to refer to Chrome.

Comment: i marked it as answer because i found the solution with TGH's comment. thanks TGH.